# Swift unit test case should run sequentially

Tags: ios

how can i run unit test sequencially in xcode like first login test case should be executed then other..before xcode8 it used to alphabetically.Any solution for xcode8

Comment: As far as i see, the execution order is still alphabetical in `XCode8`. You would like to create dependencies between the test cases?

Comment: it no longer work for xcode 8